# PIL: draw transparent text on top of an image

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

In a project I have, I am trying to create an outline over some text. The overall idea is to offset a black text slightly transparent from the original white text.

For some reasons, I get the black text but nether in transparent. Here is the MCVE:

```
image = Image.open("spongebob.gif").convert("RGBA")

draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image, "RGBA")
font = ImageFont.truetype("impact.ttf", 25)
draw.text((0, 0), "This text should be 5% alpha", fill=(0, 0, 0, 15), font=font)
image.save("foo.gif")
```

The result:

[image: Sponge Bob not happy]

What did I miss?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This should work for you.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

image = Image.open("spongebob.gif").convert("RGBA")
txt = Image.new('RGBA', image.size, (255,255,255,0))

font = ImageFont.truetype("impact.ttf", 25)
d = ImageDraw.Draw(txt)    

d.text((0, 0), "This text should be 5% alpha", fill=(0, 0, 0, 15), font=font)
combined = Image.alpha_composite(image, txt)    

combined.save("foo.gif")
```

edit: The reference example from the Pillow documentation
https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageDraw.html#example-draw-partial-opacity-text

Comment: This is somehow I also solved my issue. Do you have any idea why this is working like this ? Why drawing directly the text on the image doesn't work ?

Comment: @FunkySayu I don't have an idea why it works that way, never looked into it.  I've always just treated it like layers in a typical image editor (e.g. Paint.NET) where if you want to adjust the opacity of some element you put it on its own layer and then merge down to get your final product.  Why it doesn't behave like `alpha` in matplotlib is beyond me.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thank you.