# Transparant text in watermark

Tags: python, tkinter

I am working on adding a text on image but it appears as solid text not transparent.
I have tried with rgba transparent opacity but it shows error that it only accept integer not float.
Anybody can help? here is the code-

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter.ttk import *
from PIL import ImageFont
from PIL import ImageDraw
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

def watermark(file ,water_mark_text):
    image = Image.open(file)

    
    image_width,image_height =image.size
    
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
  
    font_size=int(image_width/4)

    font=ImageFont.truetype('arial.ttf',font_size)
    # add watermark
    draw.text((int(image_width/2), int(image_height/1.5)),water_mark_text ,fill="#B7B7B7", stroke_fill="#222",anchor='ms',font=font)
    
    image.show()

def open_file():
    file=filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir='Users\xyz') 
    watermark(file,"Demo")
    
window=Tk()
window.title("Water Mark APP")
window.geometry('500x200')

lable=Label(text="Select the image",font=("Arial", 25))
lable.pack()
lable.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.3, anchor=CENTER)
Button1=Button(text="select image",command=open_file)
Button1.pack()
Button1.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: This question "[PIL: draw transparent text on top of an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47123649/pil-draw-transparent-text-on-top-of-an-image)" may help.